# can not give input of y and z. I can only get x as an input. Can anybody please tell me what did I do wrong

Tags: c, printf, scanf

[can only put x as an input. y and z does not show up.Tried to change the data types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSBI4.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. [edit] your question and add the code as text.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues here:

1. your second argument to scanf should point to the location of your variable, ie:

   ```
   scanf("%d",&x);
   ```

This will place the scanned in value at x's location. As is now, you are putting it at *x, which is null, and will not do what you're expecting, if anything. You should make all of your scanf statements look like that

2. You're doing something with scanf that you're probably not intending. Remove the \n. [Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

3. Your final math equation that you're putting into the variable double c might not be doing what you're expecting. You should probably cast to double before starting the equation. If the compiler assumes you're doing integer math, it might round all of your fractional math to 0. You can cast like this:

   ```
   c = (((double)x + y)*z)/x - 2;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The warning says that `scanf` expects an `int` *pointer* (where to store the input), not an `int`*value* (0 in your case).

Change the `scanf` parameters `x` to `&x` etc.